# setting up EJBCA and Signserver together

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, ejbca

I need to set up SignServer and EJBCA on one Wildfly server. 
unfortunately I don't quite understand how can it be deployed because there are duplicate resources while asking for ports I did gave different ports to add.

Is there any possibility to deploy both on one server?

below I provide logs for SignServer and EJBCA first is for SignServer second is for EJBCA

SignServer

```
data-source add --name=signserverds --driver-name="mariadb-java-client.jar" --connection-url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/signserver" --jndi-name="java:/SignServerDS" --use-ccm=true --driver-class="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" --user-name="signserver" --password="signserver" --validate-on-match=true --background-validation=false --prepared-statements-cache-size=50 --share-prepared-statements=true --min-pool-size=5 --max-pool-size=150 --pool-prefill=true --transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED --check-valid-connection-sql="select 1;" --enabled=true
:reload
/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm:add()
/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(keystore-path="keystore/keystore.jks", keystore-relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir", keystore-password="serverpwd", alias="localhost")
:reload
/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm/authentication=truststore:add(keystore-path="keystore/truststore.jks", keystore-relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir", keystore-password="changeit")
:reload
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=httpspriv:add(port="443",interface="httpspriv")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=httpspriv:add(socket-binding="httpspriv", security-realm="SSLRealm", verify-client=REQUIRED, max-post-size="50485760", enable-http2="true") 
:reload
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:add(port="80",interface="http")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:add(socket-binding=http, max-post-size="50485760", enable-http2="true")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=redirect-socket, value="httpspriv")
:reload

/subsystem=remoting/http-connector=http-remoting-connector:remove
/subsystem=remoting/http-connector=http-remoting-connector:add(connector-ref="remoting",security-realm="ApplicationRealm")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=remoting:add(port="447")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=remoting:add(socket-binding=remoting, max-post-size="10485760", enable-http2="true")
:reload
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING:remove()
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING:add(value=UTF-8)
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING:remove()
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING:add(value=true)
:reload
```

EJBCA

```
data-source add --name=ejbcads --driver-name="mariadb-java-client.jar" --connection-url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ejbca" --jndi-name="java:/EjbcaDS" --use-ccm=true --driver-class="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" --user-name="ejbca" --password="ejbca" --validate-on-match=true --background-validation=false --prepared-statements-cache-size=50 --share-prepared-statements=true --min-pool-size=5 --max-pool-size=150 --pool-prefill=true --transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED --check-valid-connection-sql="select 1;"
:reload
/subsystem=remoting/http-connector=http-remoting-connector:remove
/subsystem=remoting/http-connector=http-remoting-connector:add(connector-ref="remoting",security-realm="ApplicationRealm")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=remoting:add(port="4447")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=remoting:add(socket-binding=remoting)
:reload
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.ejbca:add
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.ejbca:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.cesecore:add
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.cesecore:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
:reload
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:remove
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:remove
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:remove
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=https:remove
:reload
/interface=http:add(inet-address="0.0.0.0")
/interface=httpspub:add(inet-address="0.0.0.0")
/interface=httpspriv:add(inet-address="0.0.0.0")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:add(port="8080",interface="http")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=http:add(socket-binding=http)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=http:write-attribute(name=redirect-socket, value="httpspriv")
:reload
/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm:add()
/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(keystore-path="${jboss.server.config.dir}/keystore/keystore.jks", keystore-password="serverpwd", alias="localhost")
/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm/authentication=truststore:add(keystore-path="${jboss.server.config.dir}/keystore/truststore.jks", keystore-password="changeit")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=httpspriv:add(port="8443",interface="httpspriv")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=httpspub:add(port="8442", interface="httpspub")
:shutdown(restart=true)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=httpspriv:add(socket-binding=httpspriv, security-realm="SSLRealm", verify-client=REQUIRED)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=httpspriv:write-attribute(name=max-parameters, value="2048")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=httpspub:add(socket-binding=httpspub, security-realm="SSLRealm")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=httpspub:write-attribute(name=max-parameters, value="2048")
:reload
/system-property=org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH:add(value=true)
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH:add(value=true)
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING:add(value="UTF-8")
/system-property=org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING:add(value=true)
/subsystem=webservices:write-attribute(name=wsdl-host, value=jbossws.undefined.host)
/subsystem=webservices:write-attribute(name=modify-wsdl-address, value=true)
:reload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done.

First install Ejbca. Configure it the way you want. Then before installing signserver change the default port numbers like 8080 8442 8443 in the signserver .config files.

Comment: I actually used domain setup for Wildfly. You can check it out here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Domain+Setup?_sscc=t